Is it possible to connect to an existing headless browser instance using selenium?
I'm able to connect to an existing Chrome browser instance when using "remote-debugging-port". I can't however connect to an existing headless instance of Chrome. Getting this message: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:8989
I've tried a number of different options such as --remote-allow-origins=* and --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0, but neither allow the connection to happen.

Why would you want to connect to an existing headless browser? If it's already running, that implies some other process is puppeteering it and it's likely a bad idea to try and do that from two separate processes?

My script involves executing commands in the context of logged in user. By reusing the browser session it bypasses the need to log in each time.

Share your code so we can have a look

Then my suggestion would be to write a simple helper script, that keeps the browser session alive, and if you have scripts that need to be able to restart or run in parallel, they can connect to that script (on something like a socket or websocket, which is relatively simple to implement) and it can pass on to Selenium. You could also consider looking at something like RPyC if you don't want to write your own plumbing.
